# auto_now_add and auto_now as epoch

Tags: django, django-models, python-3.6

I wanted to save the `created_at (auto_now_add = True)` and `updated_at (auto_now = true)` fields as **epoch**

## Model

```
class EpochTest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    # Auto-update Field

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

How do I do that?

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Not the usual timestamp like `2019-12-23 10: 20: 47.804571`, I wanted to save these fields as **epoch**. But I don't know how to do it. What changes do I need to make?

Comment: Django doesn't save datetime as epoch/unix-timestamp. You should do it manually

Answer (score 0):

django does not store datetime in unix-timestamp you will have to do it manually you can achieve that via

```
datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp()
```

and you can also refer to documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add)